# Best way to save a sorting order for rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table where the rows have a particular order.  Users can insert new rows at any place in the ordering.

Our current strategy is:

- Use column called "order_index" with `Integer` type
- Have rows with their "order_index" separated by 10000
- When new row is inserted, assign integer halfway in between its neighbors
- If rows become too tightly packed (have separation of one), then lock and re-assign "order_index" to all rows, incrementing by 10000

This is obviously somewhat complex and the re-assigning is not optimal since it takes longer than we'd like.  **Any better approach to this?**

Comment: Are there any indexing/retrieval requirements? My mind initially went to a linked-list for this kind of problem, such as something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65205/linked-list-in-sql#answer-65295). Insert times would be very quick, but retrieval times might be pretty slow.

Comment: @Garrett A little bit more context is necessary here for providing a solution. Could you explain how do you decide a new row should lie between start and end range. For example, a new row should be between 10000  and 20000

Comment: You have not indicated how the user indicates where in the sequence the row is to follow, but for order_index use numeric rather an integer. The initial 2 rows can be set to any desired value. Then when inserting just average the order_index  previous and next rows to get the order_index of the current row. ( Note: a [numeric](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-numeric.html) column provides up to 16383 digits after the decimal point so plenty of room). For new first or last order_index add or subtract any value. The exact process works is user can reorder the order_index.

Comment: @JonWarren a linked list would solve the problem, although we tried that first and the data never stayed pristine (it ended with some messiness like cycles).

Comment: @SUMITPATRO we know the row that the new row should come after.

Comment: @Belayer, thanks!  Good point, the 16,383 digits of `numeric` would buy us ~54K binary splits (assuming we take strategy of averaging neighbors when inserting) before needing to reindex (or ~450K splits using the digits before decimal too).  The only downside being a slight loss in readability and DB size (will have to look into that).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to store sort order in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826829/whats-the-best-way-to-store-sort-order-in-sql)

Comment: @Dai, thanks, but no, it appears [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39871377/2223706) that contains a solution just says to do it the way in my question, I was hoping there was a better way.

Answer (score -1):

If you use a floating point index, there is always a number halfway in between.

Comment: Was thinking that too at first, but realized floating point data type actually can have 2 numbers that are maximally close to each other and there's no option in between them (given they have finite precision).

Comment: Yeah, the assertion in this comment is blatantly incorrect.